# Using jQuery.getJSON success function to change JSON result

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, getjson, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using JQuery UI's [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) widget with a [JSON remote source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).  If I type in "ba" for example, the autocomplete expects a array of strings such as ["bat", "banana", "band", "bar"].  However, my remote function to get this information is quite complex, it returns something like this:

```
{ "prefix": "ba",
  "weblog": "gmazza",
  "tagcounts": [
    { "tag" : "bat", "count" : 2 }, 
    { "tag" : "banana", "count" : 1 }, 
    { "tag" : "band", "count" : 1 }, 
    { "tag" : "bar", "count" : 1 }
  ]
}
```

...requiring me to go to the array at the third element "tagcounts" and collect the values for the string "tag" and return an array of those values.  Granted, the most sensible solution would be to change that function to a format that autocomplete can directly work with, but I'd like to learn how to write a parsing function with JQuery to change the format of the returned JSON array, i.e., for:

```
.autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("myURL", { term: 'ba' }, function(data) {...});
    },
    ...
});
```

How can I create a "success" function(data) that will give me the desired array that autocomplete needs?  Any tips, suggestions, code examples would be appreciated, this is proving more difficult to search on the 'Net than I thought.  One particular problem I'm having is that most success functions I see are just outputting to the console or creating HTML elements, I need it to return a value (JSON array) that will get used as the "response" above to my source function.

Comment: Looks like in your success function you'll need to loop through the tagcounts array and push the tag value into a seperate array, then return that array to autocomplete

Comment: Yes, I need help with the syntax as I'm still quite new with JQuery.

Comment: Try this in your success callback: `var output = [];
for(result in data.tagcounts) {
    output.push(data.tagcounts[result].tag);
} return output;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For autocomplete to work you need to set `label` and it's corresponding `value`. As you have the JSON in following format ,

```
{ "prefix": "ba",
  "weblog": "gmazza",
  "tagcounts": [
    { "tag" : "bat", "count" : 2 }, 
    { "tag" : "banana", "count" : 1 }, 
    { "tag" : "band", "count" : 1 }, 
    { "tag" : "bar", "count" : 1 }
  ]
}
```

And I believe `tagcounts.tag` needs to be the `label` and for value I don't know.

So, Use this in the `source` of **autocomplete** ,

```
source: function (request, response) {
    $.getJSON("myURL", { term: 'ba' }, function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.tagcounts, function (dataValue) {
                            return {
                                //Display label
                                label: dataValue.tag,
                                /autocomplete value
                                value: dataValue.tag
                            };
                        }))
      });
```

Comment: Great solution, works fine for me, thx. (I modified to mention just one of label or value is needed if you're setting them to the same value), in one small block it shows how to navigate the JSON response and well as return a modified JSON response.